# Set series collection as range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a chart with a collection series. I would like to extend the range of the collection series by one column to the right. The code below works. However, it assumes that I know the range of the collection series ("B36:DA36" in the example below). In fact, I would like the initial range of the collection series (before resizing) to be defined in a dynamic way as it changes every day and defining it as below would not do the job.

```
Sub resize_collection_series()

Dim NumRows As Long
Dim NumCols As Long
Dim Rng As Range

Set Rng = Range("B36:DA36")

NumRows = Rng.Rows.Count
NumCols = Rng.Columns.Count

Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 6").Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Select
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Rng.Resize(, NumCols + 1)
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Rng.Resize(, NumCols + 1)
End Sub
```

I tried something like this withouth success:

```
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").SeriesCollection(1)
Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6").SeriesCollection(1).Values
```

Comment: how exactly are you trying to set a `Range` to `SeriesCollection(1)` ? how exactly is your `Rng` dynamic ? where does it shift to ? what column or row ?

Comment: The range of the series collection starts as A12:M12. Everyday I am adding a new data column at the right, i.e. day 1 = A12:N12, day 2 = A12:O12. The added data should be incorporated in the chart through the macro. FYI: I have many charts that in the end I would like to update through the macro. I just have to figure out the principle of how to do that for one. If you ask me "how exactly are you trying to set a Range to SeriesCollection(1)". That is exacltly my question ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below to set the "Chart 6" `SeriesCollection(1)` dynamically to the number of existing column at row 12 (according to your comments).

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub resize_collection_series()

Dim NumRows As Long
Dim NumCols As Long
Dim Rng As Range
Dim LastCol As Long

Dim MyCht As ChartObject
Dim Ser As Series

' get dynamic last column at row 12
LastCol = Cells(12, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

' set the Range dynamic
Set Rng = Range(Cells(12, 1), Cells(12, LastCol))

' set "Chart 6" to MyCht Variable
Set MyCht = Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 6")
With MyCht
    Set Ser = .Chart.SeriesCollection(1)
    With Ser
        .Values = "=" & Rng.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal)

    End With
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. The code searches for the last column. How would the code have to be changed if the whole row 12 has content. It contains 0 in each cell as a formula is inserted into this cells. When cells elsewhere in the file are populated with content the cells in row 12 give a value >0. Thus, instead of code searching for the last row I am looking for code extending my SeriesCollection by one cell. Or maybe one could change your code that it looks for the last column that is not 0?

Comment: If you want to go to the last column your code works very nicely :-)